# Is there any diet beer?

Tags: specialty-beers

I want to drink beer because I feel stress of my life. However, I don't want to gain weight because I have been overweighted. Is there any diet beer in US?

Comment: What do you mean by "Diet" beer? Calorie-free or low-calorie beer?

Comment: As low calories as possible

Comment: The answer by Ryan is good, but on another tangent I might suggest that alcohol is likely not the best way to handle stress in your life.  You might want to consider other life changes like exercise, or removing stressors first.

Comment: If you want to get drunk and not take in calories try drinking clear liquours...

Answer (score 5):

This is what would be referred to as the "Light Beer" category. For the most part, this is mass-produced beer, done by the big commercial breweries in the USA (I don't know much about beer production outside North America).

If you want some good light beers, I'd suggest taking a look at lists like [BeerAdvocate's Best Light Lagers](http://www.beeradvocate.com/lists/style/39/)

Comment: Additionally:  Lots of dry (rather than sweet) beers are fairly low calorie.  Guinness as an example only has 125 calories per 12 ounce serving, which is barely more than Bud Light.

Also session beers which are low in alcohol will also have fewer calories than their more boozy compatriots.

Answer (score 1):

In Canada you can get Molson 67, which comes in at 3% alcohol and 67 calories for 12 ounces. That's about as light as there is.

Answer (score 1):

Light beer is the closest thing to diet, but here's the catch: The majority of caloric content in beer is from alcohol. If you want really low calories you're going to be looking at really low alcohol beer.

Not really a win. Best thing to do is try to cut calories elsewhere, because at that point you're drinking tasteless light beer and not even getting the proper buzz.

Answer (score 0):

This beer may be the best of all the light beer.

Bud Light (110 calories)

[image: BugLightPhoto]

Answer (score 0):

Something like Miller 64 is probably what you are looking for. But alcohol content is quite proportional to caloric content.

Answer (score -2):

if you use the Google translator - here's a description of one of these diets [пивная диета](http://evehealth.ru/pivnaya-dieta-dlya-pokhudeniya/)

Comment: Welcome to Beer.SE! Could you possibly translate and quote some of the more pertinent parts of the linked article into your answer? Without that, I'm afraid this answer doesn't meet Stack Exchange's general quality requirements.

Comment: That article seems to be about building a diet around drinking beer every day.  Idea seems to be that for 1 week a month you drink no more than 1 liter of beer every day, 2 liters of water, and eat very few calories (~800) focusing mostly on meat and veg and don't have too much salt.  Which is pretty much a regular diet, just with a codified beer allowance.  Including beer as part of calorie counting is definitely valid, but this seems like an odd approach.